# Display diffrent content in a DIV base on which link you click

Tags: php, css, class, html

I have a demo website I have been trying out some capabilities on. What I am trying to do is only display the DIVs with green or blue based on which link you click into the page.

Here is the example main page i use right now, however it requires me to build 3 separate pages to display results; all.php, green.php, and blue.php. I would like to have only one page and hide or show DIVs as needed

```
<?php


    // which page should be shown now
    $page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';



    // only the pages listed here can be accessed
    // any other pages will result in error
     $allowedPages = array('home',
        'all',
        'blue',
        'green',


     )
    ;


        if (!in_array($page, $allowedPages) || !file_exists($page . '.php')) {
            $page = 'notfound';
        } 

        // set prettier title
        //$title .= ($page != 'home') ? ' - ' . ucfirst($page) : '';



    // start output buffering so headers can be used in sub pages
            ob_start();



    ?> <html>
          <head>
            <title>tester</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="sucker.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <ul id="nav">
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=all">All Color</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?page=green">Greew/a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="index.php?page=blue">Blue</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php


        include($page . '.php');

        ?>

          </body>
        </html>
```

This is the content of all.php

```
        <div style="min-height: 245px; border: 2px solid transparent;" class="itemWrapper">
            <a class="itemLink" href="http://www.demo.com/products/blue1.jpg">
            <img src="images/products/hold.jpg" class="itemImage" style="width:150px;;height:150px;;"/></a>
            <h3 class="itemTitle"> Blue Item 1</a></h3>
            <p class="itemPrice">$5.00</p>
            <img style="display: none;" class="quickViewBtn" src="images/products/quick_view.png" />
        </div>

        <div style="min-height: 245px; border: 2px solid transparent;" class="itemWrapper">
            <a class="itemLink" href="http://www.demo.com/products/blue2.jpg">
            <img src="images/products/hold.jpg" class="itemImage" style="width:150px;;height:150px;;"/></a>
            <h3 class="itemTitle"> Blue Item 2</a></h3>
            <p class="itemPrice">$3.00</p>
        <img style="display: none;" class="quickViewBtn" src="images/products/quick_view.png" /></div>

        <div style="min-height: 245px;" class="itemWrapper">
            <a class="itemLink" href="http://www.demo.com/products/blue3.jpg">
            <img src="images/products/hold.jpg" class="itemImage" style="width:150px;;height:150px;;"/></a>
            <h3 class="itemTitle"> Blue Item 3</a></h3>
            <p class="itemPrice">$4.00</p>
        <img style="display: none;"  class="quickViewBtn" src="images/products/quick_view.png" alt= "Quick View" /></div>

        <div style="min-height: 245px;" class="itemWrapper last">
            <a class="itemLink" href="http://www.demo.com/products/green1.jpg">
            <img src="images/products/hold.jpg" class="itemImage" style="width:150px;;height:150px;;"/></a>
            <h3 class="itemTitle"> Green Item 1</a></h3>
            <p class="itemPrice">$1.00</p>
        <img style="display: none;"  class="quickViewBtn" src="images/products/quick_view.png" /></div>

          <div style="min-height: 245px;" class="itemWrapper last">
            <a class="itemLink" href="http://www.demo.com/products/green2.jpg">
            <img src="images/products/hold.jpg" class="itemImage" style="width:150px;;height:150px;;"/></a>
            <h3 class="itemTitle"> Green Item 2</a></h3>
            <p class="itemPrice">$2.00</p>
        <img style="display: none;"  class="quickViewBtn" src="images/products/quick_view.png" /></div>

      </div>
```

Any help you can provide would be great!

Comment: Are those divs all together on a page? Do you have some sort of loop to put those together?

Comment: You've got a malformed end anchor tag in your html on the green link.

Comment: They are currently hand jammed, i would like to auto generate in the future

Comment: But green and blue items would never appear on the same page?

Comment: They currently do on the all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery/JavaScript is the way to go here if you want it to be seamless, but since you're saying this is just a sort of "test" site, I assume you are doing it more to experiment with PHP and have fun. So, what you need to do is put all three pages into one file, then wrap all three pages inside an if...then statement. Effectively:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['page'])) {
    //let the user make a choice
} else if ($_POST['page'] == 'green') {
    ?> 
    <!--HTML for the "green" pages goes here!-->
    <?php
} else if ($_POST['page'] == 'blue') {
    ?> 
    <!--HTML for the "blue" pages goes here!-->
    <?php
} else {
    print("Invalid page selection!"); //Keep in mind, we want to "error check" to make sure the user actually selected a page
}
?>
```

If you had many more "pages", you should use a switch statement. If this were a really big application you could use an `include()` statement (but make sure you check that the file exists!) and just include multiple styled files inside your application.

Comment: I have 20 right now this was just a expert. 5 red 5 green 5 blue and 5 yellow

Comment: This looks like what I want to do, and yes having a little fun with PHP is the order of the day. however I tried this on the site and nothing shows up (note: I added the divs to your code)

Comment: Thanks for the help<?php
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') ? $_GET['page'] : 'all';


if ($page == 'green') {
    ?> 
    HTML for the green pages goes here!
    <?php
} else if ($page == 'blue') {
    ?> 
    HTML for the blue pages goes here!
    <?php
} else {
    print("Invalid page selection!"); 
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

You could load it all, and have them in different classes, and load them using jQuery.  I made an example - check it out [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eV5gp/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".green").hide();
    $(".blue").hide();
```

Something like that - and then showing them onclick of the buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I copied the example and it shows all of the divs all the time

Comment: Great example site, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: Did you click on the buttons in the example at the bottom of it?  When you have it show blue, it shows all the blue, but the buttons are still there (at the bottom, but you probably have to scroll).  Then green would do the same thing, etc.  It seems to be working for me... Just to be clear, I'm using jQuery to do this, so if you don't have jQuery loaded, then it's not going to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just write something like this into your body tag

```
<body class="
<?php

... if isset... if in_array
switch ($page)
{ 
    case "green":
        echo "body_green";
    break;

    case "blue":
        echo "body_blue";
    break;

    default:
        echo "";
}
?>
">
```

And in your CSS

```
.green, .blue {
  display:none;
}

.body_green .green {
  display: block;
}

...
```